# Hibernate - Query Works in MySQL WorkBench But Hibernate Throws Exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using the following named query:

```
@NamedQuery(name="FseLiveLocation.findByMultipleIds", query = "SELECT f FROM FseLiveLocation f inner join (SELECT max(fl.id) ide FROM FseLiveLocation fl WHERE fl.fseInfoId IN (:fseInfoList) GROUP BY fl.fseInfoId) j on f.id=j.ide")
```

The query works fine in mysql:

```
select f.* from fse_live_location f join (SELECT max(fl.id) as ide FROM Fse_Live_Location fl WHERE fl.fse_Info_Id IN
(12578740, 24910) GROUP BY fl.fse_Info_Id) as j on f.id=j.ide
```

But I get QuerySyntaxException when I try to run my code:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries:
> FseLiveLocation.findByMultipleIds failed because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 75 [SELECT f FROM com.paytm.common.dao.entity.FseLiveLocation as f inner join (SELECT max(fl.id) as ide FROM com.paytm.common.dao.entity.FseLiveLocation as fl WHERE fl.fseInfoId IN (:fseInfoList) GROUP BY fl.fseInfoId) as j on f.id=j.ide]
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:337)
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
> ... 64 more

Comment: \@NamedQuery expects a HQL or JPQL query, not a SQL query. If you want to use a SQL query, you need to use \@NamedNativeQuery

Answer (score 0):

That query simply is invalid HQL. HQL does not support subqueries in the FROM clause. You can rewrite this query though:

```
@NamedQuery(name="FseLiveLocation.findByMultipleIds", query = "SELECT f FROM FseLiveLocation f where f.id IN (SELECT max(fl.id) ide FROM FseLiveLocation fl WHERE fl.fseInfoId IN (:fseInfoList) GROUP BY fl.fseInfoId)")
```